# Is there any way to implement stop() for Standalone Spring Boot application as a service/daemon?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, start-stop-daemon

I'd like to know how to implement stop() method as Apache Commons Daemon provides on Spring Boot.

I read the related documentation from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html, and it seems that the Spring Boot 1.3.x or later version supports being started as a service/daemon using systemctl command on Linux (especially CentOS, which is my current environment for testing).

A Spring Boot Application seems being able to be stated/stopped with a script and the systemctl command, but there is no description about the my question. The reason I need the function is because Apache Kafka is used on the application so that it should do close() when it stopped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Who's starting the application? Who's stopping the application? Is it the same process?

Comment: This is a long withstanding problem known as XY problem http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll, a system administrator has a role to start/stop the application.

Comment: @MarkoBonaci, the reason I'd want to use Spring Boot is to use the function embedding Tomcat/Undertow.

Comment: I am afraid that does not answer my question at all. What is your target OS? In 1.3 we support linux services out of the box.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll, the target OS is CentOS 7, I mentioned this except the version though.

Comment: What's wrong with [our current support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-service)?

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll The SpringBoot supports starting/stopping service  as Linux services, but my question is how to execute some methods while stopping the app... For example, ThreadPoolTaskExecutor should be shutdown when the app is going to be stopped.

Comment: And I tested the way described http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-service, but it seems not working for me... I tested it via very simple spring-boot app, which automatically created, but the result showed "failed" while starting the app as a service via systemd. The app is obviously executable via "java -jar myapp.jar" though.